# Spring Data R2DBC - Building custom postgresql query with array of strings

Tags: java, spring-boot, r2dbc-postgresql

I use R2DBC repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StockRepo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Stock, Long> {
Flux<Stock> searchByArrayValueIgnoreCase(String[] arr);

}
```

I need to create custom query to postgres like `"select * from stocks where title like any (array['%1%', '%2%', '%3%']);"`

I send String[] arr in to repository;

in my repository:

```
@Query("select * from stocks where title like any WHAT") 
    Flux<Stock> searchByArrayValueIgnoreCase(String[] arr);
```

What I need to write instead of "WHAT" in query?

I tried  @Query("select * from stocks where title like any (array[:#{#arr}])")  but received error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No parameter specified for [__synthetic_0__]] in query [select * from stocks where title like any (array[:__synthetic_0__])]
```